# Curl Batch file HTTP POST URI

Tags: silverlight, batch-file, curl, http-post, uri

I need help. This is my first time asking a question here but have found plenty of great answers and I am hoping somebody can help me. I am trying to create a HTTP POST via a batch file utilizing Curl. I have successfully set up my headers and have grabbed all the required information from WireShark however I am stuck. I cant seem to get the POST BODY correct. Can somebody point me in the right direction? My ultimate goal is to simulate the same action as clicking a button in a silverlight web app that generates a backup file. 
This is my current HTTP POST with headers. When you get to the data -d you will see the POST DATA I found wire shark displaying.

`curl -H "Accept: " -H "User-Agent: " -H "Content-Type: " -H "Host:xx.xx.xx.xx" -H "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0" -H "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate" -H "Connection:keep-alive" -H "Content-Type:application/msbin1" -H "Content-Length:53" -H "Referer:http:/xx.xx.xx.xx/ClientBin/System_Management_Center.xap" -X POST -d @BackupConfighttp://tempuri.org/@sysTypesmVACS http://xx.xx.xx.xx/ClientBin/System_Management_Center-Web-Services-VACSDomainService.svc/binary/BackupConfig`

The results of running this in my batch file says could not read file, this makes an empty post. 
I noticed that copying the post data to a webbrowser shows it contains more than is displaying in wireshark. It appears as @BackupConfighttp://tempuri.org/@sysType™smVACS and when searched google returns
@BackupConfig%08%13http://tempuri.org/@%07sysType%06smVACS

I tired replacing my -d line with the returned data from google and the batch file returns "Couldn't read data from file, "BakupConfigC:\users\sean\desktop\genera~1.BAT83http://tempuri.org/@C:\users\sean\desktop\genera~1.bat7sysTypeC:\users\sean\desktop\genera~1.bat6smVACS", this makes an empty POST.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: *update* I have found that the post data contains Unicode characters. The expanded version of the post data looks something like this 
`@(Form Feed)BackupConfig(Backspace)(Device Control 3)http://tempuri.org/@(Bell Ring)sysType(Acknowledge)smVACS(Start of Header)` 
Hopefully with this information somebody can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the issue is because your POST data starts with a `@` character, which is being handled bu curl as a pointer to a local path.

from [this link](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d)

> if you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file
>   name to read the data from.

so to fix this, you will need to replace the `@` with `%40` which is the encoded version of `@`.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tired your recommendation and the batch file didn't give any errors which is progress! However with my post data as `%40BackupConfighttp://tempuri.org/@sysTypesmVACS` returns a bad request (monitored by wireshark)
Wireshark shows a post data of `0.BackupConfig..http://tempuri.org/@.sysType-..smVACS.`
The original post data I am trying to mimic as shown by wireshark is `@.BackupConfig..http://tempuri.org/@.sysType..smVACS.`

Comment: you might also need to add quotes to your post data since it contains spaces.

Comment: I so appreciate yalls help! @Pupa Rebbe, I tried your suggestion and my batch file has an error now. Warning: Couldn't read data from file "♀BackupConfi!!http://tempura.org/@sysType-ö♠smVACS☺", this makes an empty POST.